# MKMarkerAnnotationView selectAnnotation() shows both, MarkerView and callout

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

In my `MKMapView` I show a `MKMarkerAnnotationView`

[image: MKMarkerAnnotationView]

This looks as intended.

When I tap on it manually, the, the MarkerView is rendered as a point and the callout is shown:

[image: Callout]

When I select the corresponding `MKAnnotation` programmatically like this

```
mapView.selectAnnotation(copiedAnnotation, animated: false)
```

in the main thread, I'd expect the same result as tapping on it.
But instead, I get this:

[image: eCallout and marker]

So the MarkerView is rendered in a size that would be correct if there was no callout. And the correct callout is rendered on top of it.

`animated: false/true` makes no difference.

What can I do that MapKit renders `selectAnnotation` the same way as a tap on a `MKMarkerAnnotationView`?

This happens in iOS 11 and 12.0.

**Edit**

It's a timing problem. When calling

```
mapView.selectAnnotation(copiedAnnotation, animated: false)
```

in the first few 100 milliseconds after adding the annotation, the bug shows. Waiting at least 600 ms before selecting programmatically appears to be a workaround. Waiting until the view appears is not enough.

**Edit 2**

Submitted a working and reproducible example to apples radar.

Comment: For me work just fine, maybe the issue is in other part of your code. Do you implement anything in `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)`?

Comment: After further investigation it appears to be a timing problem: the annotation is selected immediately after adding it. See edit.